# wp_dropdown_users() to include null value

Tags: users

Is there an argument for `wp_dropdown_users()` which would add a blank null value (no user selected)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'show_option_none' argument for this.

```
wp_dropdown_users( array('show_option_none'        => __('No user selected') ) );
```